# .NET SqlClient - Transmission of credentials encrypted?

Tags: .net, sqlclient

I have already spent some time trying to get some information on the following question.

Application in .Net 4.5.2.
A connection is made to a MS-SQL database.
The connection is done by SQL Server Authentication via User & Password.

```
            string connString = String.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};UID={2};Password={3}", server, database, user, password);

            SqlConnection SQLConn = null;
            SQLConn = new SqlConnection(connString);
            SQLConn.Open();
```

How exactly is the connection established?
Are the access data/password transmitted in plain text over the network, or is this already based on an encrypted connection?

No certificates are set up from the SQL Server and "Force Encryption" in the SQL Server Configuration Manager is set to "no".

I am primarily concerned with the login process.
Not about keeping the connection string in the memory of the client / server or similar.

I tried to get this information via google and from the MS doc.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what your server setup is, even if encryption is not requested by server, the handshake and TDS login always are encrypted. For the rest you can set it up in your connection string with "Encrypt" property. Prior to TDS8 or lets say SQL Server 2022 you could set it up as a Boolean true or false. In SQL Server 2022 that has been changed to Optional, Mandatory and Strict. The new values are also back port compatible. True is same as Mandatory and Optional is same as false. By setting Encrypt value to Strict you force the driver and the Server to use TDS8 protocol and in result TLS 1.3 and that certainly needs a SSL/TLS certificate.